# Dockerで画像収集Pythonプログラムを実行した時に、画像保存先を指定したい

Tags: python, docker

Dockerのコンテナ内で画像取集pythonプログラムを実行すると、Dockerコンテナ内に画像が保存されます。
以下が画像収集プログラムです。

```
from icrawler.builtin import BaiduImageCrawler, BingImageCrawler, GoogleImageCrawler
    crawler = GoogleImageCrawler(storage={"root_dir": "images"})
    crawler.crawl(keyword="猫", max_num=100)
```

図で示すと以下のようになります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし私はコンテナ内ではなく、Windowsのフォルダに保存したいのです。
保存先を通常のフォルダに変更することは可能なのでしょうか？
アドバイスをいただきたいです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`-v` オプションで任意のボリューム (フォルダ、ディレクトリ) のマウントを行う事ができます。

```
docker run -v [ホストディレクトリの絶対パス]:[コンテナの絶対パス] [イメージ名] [コマンド]
```

```
docker run -v /src/volume:/dst/volume python /bin/bash
```

**参考:**
[コンテナでデータを管理する - Docker-docs-ja](http://docs.docker.jp/engine/userguide/dockervolumes.html)

Comment: 試してみたのですがうまくプログラムが実行されませんでした。Error response from daemon: Container ~ is not running　というエラー文が出てきました。

Comment: 説明はあくまでも一例なので、実際の環境に合わせて読み替えてもらう必要があります (回答は "こんなオプションがあるよ" に的を絞った内容です)。

Comment: なるほど。では今回の場合だと、ホストディレクトリの絶対パスがwindows側で、コンテナの絶対パスがコンテナのフォルダという認識で合っていますでしょうか？？